# jquery autocomplete Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, frontend, jquery-autocomplete

```
$('#tags').autocomplete({
    params: {search_type:$('#search-type').val()},
    minChars: 2,
    appendTo: $(".cash-collection-select"),
    serviceUrl: '/admin/journals/search_roles',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
      $("#q").val(suggestion.data);
      console.log(suggestion.data)
      alert("You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data")
    },
    onSearchStart: function(query) {
    console.log("query: "+query)
    },
    onSearchComplete: function (query, suggestions) {
      console.log(suggestions.data)
    }
  });
```

I am getting the error Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined. My response from the rails action is coming in json format

```
suggestions = User.where("email LIKE ?","#{params[:query]}%")
    message = {:query => "Unit", :suggestions => suggestions}
    render :json => message
```

this is my input #tags

```
<input class="search-emails" type="email" id="tags" placeholder="Search by email.." />
```

Comment: Can you post any link where this page can be tested live? That would make it easier to debug.

Comment: Please edit your post and include some sample datat that would be returned by your Rails. I do not see where `.replace()` is being used, so it's not clear where the error is being generated. Is there other code involved?

Comment: You seem to also have a number of methods and options that do not exists for `.autocomplete()` from JQuery UI. Where is the docs for this? Are you using a plugin?

Comment: @Twisty I am not using .replace() anywhere, it's in the autocomplete.min.js

Comment: The error you encountered suggests that `.replace()` is being called on an object that undefined. So it is being used somewhere in your code or something about your code is passing a undefined object along to something else.

Comment: Thanks I got the error, my data from rails action was an array of model objects, I changed that into simple array and now its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was lying in comments for a long time, thought of moving this to an answer.

My data from rails action was an array of model objects, I changed that into ruby array and now its working fine.